Laravel queue:listen throwing "Undefined array key "queue""
I am inside my container with normal php-fpm / nginx setup and when I run php artisan queue:listen no matter what I get :
ErrorException Undefined array key "queue"

at vendor/laravel/horizon/src/Connectors/RedisConnector.php:20
16▕      */
17▕     public function connect(array $config)
18▕     {
19▕     return new RedisQueue(
          $this->redis, $config['queue'], 
          Arr::get($config, 'connection', $this->connection),
         ...

artisan:35
Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
I have installed redis already but does not seem to remedy the issue

in config/database.php find redis and add queue conf
something like :
'redis' => [
    // .....
    // .....
    'queue' => [
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => '0',
        'prefix' => 'q:'
    ],
],

and in your .env file check and set values of :
REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379


Not the solution , BTW, its in docker container so no 127.0.0.1 works here

i was trying to explain you what (and where) config .... not any single value .... i cannot even know your redis password... by the way good luck , i hope you'll find the right solution
